# Symlinking /User/SpecialFolder to different drive creates Folder in Folder

Tags: finder, macos, symlink

Just finished re-installing macOS Sierra on my MBP and am trying to move the ~/Downloads and other folders to a different drive so they end up in /Volumes/Data/ instead.

I created a /Volumes/Data/Downloads folder and *symlinked* from one to the other like so:

```
sudo ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads Downloads
```

This works more or less, but it creates another *Downloads* folder *inside* the /Volumes/Data/Downloads folder so the full path would be

```
/Volumes/Data/Downloads/Downloads
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?
So it looks like this:
[image: Downloads inside Downloads]

Comment: What directory (folder) are you in when you run the command?

Comment: I'm in *my* homefolder
As in /User/Username

Comment: OK, thanks. Did ~/Downloads exist before you made the symlink? (I can recreate this, but only when I first create a source directory with the same name as the symlink).

Comment: Yes, ~/Downloads is the default directory inside the user directory, just as ~/Documents or ~/Music - it's those _default_ directories that I want in on a different drive. I don't want to move the whole User folder as I want to keep the ~/Library in it's original place. (That is on the SSD that houses the OS too. The symlinked folders on /Data are on an HDD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurred because you already had something in your home directory called "Downloads" - the `ln` command is smart enough not to write over it, so instead created the symlink *within* it.

If you're starting from scratch you can `mv ~/Downloads ~/Volumes/Data/`; if you've already successfully copied your Downloads directory you can simply delete the old one in your home directory: `rm -Rf ~/Downloads`.

After that your original `ln` command should work. You shouldn't need to prefix it with `sudo`:

```
ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads ~/Downloads
```

Or, as fd0 suggested, instead of using `rm` you could use `ln -s -f` option to unlink the directory. Thus creating the desired results:

```
ln -s -f /Volumes/Data/Downloads ~/Downloads
```

Comment: Thanks you @John-N this did the trick.
I read about this in so many places, but it _seems_ none mentioned to remove the original folder

Comment: Instead of using `rm`, you could use `ln` 's `-f` option to unlink the directory. Thus creating the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing full path instead, I think what you wanted to write is:

```
sudo ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads ~/Downloads
```

Comment: Same thing happens

Comment: Can you run 'ls -l' from terminal from /Volumes/Data/Downloads and show the result?

Comment: Also try
 `sudo ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads /Users/{userName}/Downloads` and make sure

Comment: Also try
 `sudo ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads /Users/{userName}/Downloads`
 and make sure the folder '/Users/{userName}/Downloads' does not exists

Comment: _ls -l_ gives the following:
`$ ls -l . 
total 0 . 
drwxr-xr-x  265 username  admin  9010 Nov 21 12:00 Documents . 
drwxr-xr-x    2 username  admin    68 Dec  5 12:56 Downloads . 
drwxr-xr-x  243 username  admin  8262 Dec  5 12:58 DownloadsOLD . 
drwxr-xr-x   28 username  admin   952 Nov 20 18:48 Movies . 
drwxr-xr-x    9 username  admin   306 Jul 11  2014 Music` . 
Where _Downloads_ is the folder I am trying to link to.  

Should I remove the default /Users/UserName/Downloads before trying?

Comment: Yes, you already backed it up, so you just need to remove the directory